# How to tell, with Elisp, whether a command is running as part of a keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros

In some situations a command will use timers or hooks in a way that doesn't work when repeating as a keyboard macro.

How can I detect if a function is running as part of a keyboard macro that is being repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be checked using `(not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive))`

---

The documentation for `called-interactively-p` states:

```
Instead of using this function, it is cleaner and more reliable to give your
function an extra optional argument whose `interactive' spec specifies
non-nil unconditionally (\"p\" is a good way to do this), or via
\(not (or executing-kbd-macro noninteractive)).
```

However I couldn't figure out how that was supposed to work.